# Execution halt as the script not reading csv file

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I have created R shiny App and moved that to production. The app is working fine in R studio but once I move to the production it is showing the following error in reading csv file part.

```
here() starts at /home/production/workspace.git
Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/home/production/workspace.git/Shiny_App_for_CFM/status_var_list.csv': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: runApp ... eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> read.csv -> read.table -> file
Execution halted
```

Line of code for reading csv file is included below:

```
library(here)
status_var <- read.csv(here('Shiny_App_for_CFM/status_var_list.csv'))
status_var <- data.frame(status_var)
```

Comment: What is your question? The error message is self-explanatory.

Comment: What is the output for `file.exists("/home/production/workspace.git/Shiny_App_for_CFM/status_var_list.csv")`

Comment: Could you also be more specific on the **move to production** step ? Is it shiny, shiny-server, shinyproxy ? There is maybe also a problem of access rights from the server to the file.

Comment: Generally, data files used by the app should be stored within the defined folder structure of the app rather than with a hard coded external location.  Do you know the location in relation to the 'live' working directory of the app as opposed to the working directory of your development environment?   Can we see the line of code which references this .csv file?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen its included now in the question

Comment: can you share your `here::i_am()` call?  Is `/home/production/workspace.git` the correct project folder?  It may be that `here()` has tried to determine a default 'home' location using the process detailed in this link: https://here.r-lib.org/reference/here.html